# Why doesn't this use statement with a glob import work?

Tags: unit-testing, module, rust

I have a module I'm trying to test. The module uses nom macros to generate functions. In the test module I `use super::*`, but the functions are not brought into scope.

```
pub mod v4 {
    use nom::be_i16;
    named!(Ch_D<i16>, preceded!(tag!([0x65;1]), be_i16));
    //... lots more of these

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use super::*;
        #[test]
        #[allow(overflowing_literals)]
        fn Ch_D_test() {
            let bytes = &[0x65, 0xf0, 0xe7];
            assert_eq!(Ch_D(bytes), IResult::Done(EMPTY_SLICE,0xf0e7));
        }
    }
}
```

I get `error[E0425]: unresolved name 'Ch_D'` or if I `use super::Ch_D` it works, but I really don't want to write out every single function name.

Since the nom macros don't create public functions I don't have much choice but to make this work without marking the functions as `pub`.

Comment: The question "Why doesn't this use statement work in Rust?" is still answered in the thread marked as dupe. You probably want to ask "What's the best way to do it in my situation?"... Although I don't think there is a good answer to that. You have to list all private symbols manually in the `use`-statement... there is no way around it :/

Comment: For nom, you can add `pub` [to the named macro](https://docs.rs/nom/2.0.1/nom/macro.named.html): `named!(pub Ch_D<i16>, ...`.

Comment: @Shepmaster yeah but now that can't be an answer, now can it.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt it's the same answer: make the function public or import it by name. Stack Overflow doesn't need thousands of variations on that question and answer for every unique combination of macro syntax that crate authors decide to dream up.

Comment: Well that's where I disagree, especially when the documentation situation for Rust crates is so terrible in general.